# Why region / zone is necessary in gcloud commands

Tags: gcloud

let's consider the following command:

```
gcloud dataflow jobs drain JOB_ID --region=europe-west1 --project=project_id
```

It is just an example of command, the question is general:

Why is it necessary to give a region. Why gcloud is not able to determine it on himself? After all, I give a `project id` and `job id`. For my eye `gcloud` should be able to determine region by `project id` and `job id`.

Answer (score 0):

In relation to your general question, as mentioned in the beginning of the [Changing the Default Region or Zone](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/changing-default-zone-region) documentation, it is expected that requests related to regional resources require that you supply a region name.

For the example you provided, it is most likely that the Dataflow API looks for the JOB_ID in the specified region, this makes more sense once you look at the message returned when executing the command without the `--region` flag:

```
Could not cancel workflow; user does not have sufficient permissions on project: [PROJECT_ID], or the job does not exist in the project. Please ensure you have permission to access the job and the `--region` flag, us-central1, matches the job's region.
```

The command uses `us-central1` as the default region for the request, and the API tries to find the provided JOB_ID “inside” this region.